# How can I activate a '.js' script from R?

Tags: r, linux

I have a '.js' script that I usually activate from the terminal using the command `node script.js`. As this is part of a process where I first do some data analysis in R, I want to avoid the manual step of opening the terminal and typing the command by simply having R do it for me. My goal would be something like this:

```
...R analysis
write.csv(df, "data.csv")
system('node script.js')
```

However, when I use that specific code, I get the error:

```
sh: 1: node: not found
Warning message:
In system("node script.js") : error in running command
```

Of course, the same command runs without problem if I type it directly on the terminal.

**About my Software**

I am using:

- Linux computer with the PopOS!
- RStudio 2021.09.1+372 "Ghost Orchid"
- R version 4.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `node: not found` indicates that it couldn't find the program `node`. It's likely in PATH in your terminal's shell, but not in `system()`'s shell (sh).

In your terminal, locate `node` by executing `which node`. This will show the full path to the executable. Use that full path in `system()` instead.

Alternatively, run `echo $PATH` in your terminal, and run `system('echo $PATH')` or `Sys.getenv('PATH')` in R. Add any missing directories to R's path with `Sys.setenv(PATH = <your new path string>)`

Note that `system2()` is recommended over `system()` nowadays - but for reasons unimportant for your case. See `?system` and `?system2` for a comparison.

**Examples**

Terminal

```
$ which node
/usr/bin/node
```

R

```
system('/usr/bin/node script.js')
# alternatively:
system2('/usr/bin/node', c('script.js'))
```

or adapt your PATH permanently:

Terminal

```
% echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/home/caspar/programs:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

R

```
> Sys.getenv('PATH')
[1] "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/postback"

> Sys.setenv(PATH = "/home/caspar/programs:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/postback")
```